# How to change the color lines of FullCalendar?

Tags: css, reactjs, fullcalendar

I want to change the lines color of all calendar, they are like light gray right now, and it is difficult to read.

I want to do it using css. I saw the documentation but can´t find anything related. I am already using like .fc-toolbar-title to change colors.

Edit:I found these

```
.fc-theme-standard td, .fc-theme-standard th
```

and it works but just using `!important`. Using that I lose some characteristics like the dashed line. I just have solid ones. Inspecting the elements what I see:

```
.fc-theme-standard td, .fc-theme-standard th{ border: 1px solid var(--fc-border-color, #ddd);}
```

Edit2: I found

```
.fc-timegrid-slot-minor
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--fc-border-color, black) !important;
  border-top: 1px dotted var(--fc-border-color, black) !important;
```

Comment: Inspect the elements in your browser's dev tools to learn how they are rendered and what CSS rules are applied in order to create the grid lines. Then you'll hopefully be able to see what rule to use to override the colour.

Comment: I found these .fc-theme-standard td, .fc-theme-standard th, and it works but just using !important. Using that I loose some caracteristics like the dashed line. I just have solid ones. Inspecting the elements what I see: .fc-theme-standard td, .fc-theme-standard th{ border: 1px solid var(--fc-border-color, #ddd);}